# Most frequently used SQL Injection attacks

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-injection

I'm developing a new application and i want to test if it's vulnerable. I know some common attacks, but maybe you can provide some more to make my app safer.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this question is specific enough for Stackoverflow.  Maybe [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?  It is an interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: This is a bit too broad for Programmers SE. If you want to narrow it down and describe precisely what you're worried about, please flag this for moderator attention and perhaps it could be migrated.

Comment: @Tim P: Thanks for that explanation.  I don't have as good of an undertsanding of what's ok to put on Programmers SE.

Comment: Their [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) is pretty helpful, you can also ask on their [meta site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com) when in doubt. Programmers SE is a rather unique site in the network and a great resource, once you get to know it :) A golden rule on any Stack Exchange site is to avoid 'a list of' type questions. The more specific you can be, the better the question will be received. Additionally, what app? :P

Comment: @Tim, thank you very much. I'll grab some examples and will try to make a more precise question.

Comment: @santiagobasulto: there are plugins for browsers that perform automated tests (not only SQL injection, but also other vulnerabilities).

Comment: There is a security expertise site on SE.

Comment: @Mchl can you name some? Thanks.

Comment: @santiagobasulto: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/1792636/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to test for multiple attack vectors. Simply passing the character used to quote strings (usually,`'`) should cause a syntax error if its open to SQL injection -- unless you have an IDS or some signature-based detection standing in your way.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this post: http://ferruh.mavituna.com/sql-injection-cheatsheet-oku/
Also there's a Firefox add-on named SQL Inject Me but right now it doesn't work with Firefox 6

Answer (score 0):

- Always escape your variables with the proper function (for example, [$pdo->quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) or [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), depending on which extension you are using)
- Use **[prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)** as much as possible
- Never escape your variables too early, or you will never know whether they are escaped or not. Just escape them the most lately possible, and always consider that they are not escaped.
- Properly set the connection encoding

If you follow this you are not vulnerable to SQL injection (provided that you don't forget to escape something).

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but i'm looking for actual sql injection attacks. For example "-- DROP TABLE users"

Comment: Just insert sql-special chars (`"'` and `) in your inputs and check if you get syntax errors.

Comment: Never assume you're not vulnerable. The other side counts on it.